# How do I achieve correct placement of the xtick labels in this pgfplots example without losing any?

Tags: pgfplots, vertical-alignment, positioning, labels, missing

In the following code for a pgfplots bar chart, I use explicit xticklabels because I want simple integer labels, not exponentials or not-quite-right integers derived from them. But that means I also need to specify or adjust the placement of the xtick labels.  Using xshift almost solves the problem, but somehow it loses the first tick label --- which should be a 10 under the first group of 3 bars.  What's a good fix for this problem?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[
        log basis x=4,
        width=10cm,
        xlabel=size of input expressions,
        xticklabels={10,40,160,640,2560},
        x tick label style={xshift=2.5cm},
        xmin=5, xmax=5120,
    ylabel=geo. mean (output-size / input-size),
        yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    ybar,
]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(10,75.16) (40,76.38)
         (160,76.91) (640,77.35) (2560,77.41)};
\addplot 
    coordinates {(10,65.35) (40,59.68)
         (160,56.85) (640,57.50) (2560,57.01)};
\addplot 
    coordinates {(10,52.48) (40,23.40)
         (160,6.09) (640,1.64) (2560,0.37)};
\legend{std.,fuse,lift}
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want the ticks between the bar groups, and the tick labels directly below, or both ticks and ticklabels directly below the bar groups?

Comment: I don't need the xtick marks; I could set draw=none for these.  I'd like each label to appear beneath the middle bar in a group of three --- as the labels from 40 do, but the leftmost bar group is currently missing the label 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really just need to specify the x-values where you want the ticks. Seeings as all five groups are represented in the first `\addplot`, you can simply add `xtick=data` to the `axis` options, and remove the `xshift` for the labels.

If you want to remove the ticks you can do `x tick style={/pgfplots/tickwidth=0}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[
        log basis x=4,
        width=10cm,
        xlabel=size of input expressions,
        xticklabels={10,40,160,640,2560},
        xmin=5, xmax=5120,
        ylabel=geo. mean (output-size / input-size),
        yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
        enlargelimits=0.05,
        ybar,
        xtick=data,
        x tick style={/pgfplots/tickwidth=0}
]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(10,75.16) (40,76.38)
         (160,76.91) (640,77.35) (2560,77.41)};
\addplot 
    coordinates {(10,65.35) (40,59.68)
         (160,56.85) (640,57.50) (2560,57.01)};
\addplot 
    coordinates {(10,52.48) (40,23.40)
         (160,6.09) (640,1.64) (2560,0.37)};
\legend{std.,fuse,lift}
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```